# passing an array of objects in postgresql using node

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

```js
var query = `select * from map_balances where balance_userid = $1 AND balance_vendorid = $2 AND balance_amount >= $3`
                var values = [accesstoken,token,arr.map(e=>e.vid),arr.map(e=>e.amt)];
                client.query(query,{arr:values},async(err,projectdata)=>{
                    if (err) {
                        res.json({success:false,message:err.message,responsecode:-1});
                    } else {
                        res.json({success:true,message:projectdata.rowCount,responsecode:200});
                    }
                });
```

here `arr=[{"vid": 636,"amt": "21","add": "123123"},{"vid": 636,"amt": "21","add": "123123"},{"vid": 636,"amt": "21","add": "123123"}]` will be like this from client

here I am trying to the get data from db, arr is an array which contains no.of objects in each object "amt" is there and it should be greater then the balance in db
I am using postgres and tried some other types as well still not working

Comment: You could pass a JSON as a parameter and  parse it in postgreSQL. (BTW  your question is not understandable)

Comment: can you suggest me how to pass an array in postgresql ? like in above  – Cetin Basoz

Comment: I gave you a sample. You would simply pass your JSON string. JSON.Stringfy(yourArrJSON)

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the array json itself to postgreSQL it would look like:

```
var query = `select mb.*
from map_balances mb
    inner join jsonb_to_recordset( $1::jsonb) as x(vid int, amt int, add int)
    on mb.balance_vendorid = x.vid AND
       mb.balance_amount >= x.amt AND
       mb.balance_userid = x.add;`
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let _final = [];
_arr.forEach(e => {
    _final.push([userid, e.add, e.amt, e.vid, "NOW()"]);
})
let query1 = format(`INSERT INTO public.map_mass_payouts (mp_user_id, mp_receiver_address, mp_receiver_amount, mp_receiver_vendorid ,mp_date) values %L returning mp_id`, _final);
// console.log(query1);
client.query(query1, [], async (err, data) => {
    res.json({ success: true, responsecode: 200, message: "Request Received Successfully", _status });
})
```

and install npm i pg-format...

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.